# Конвертирование значения времени DateTime в int для shutdown C#

Tags: c#, .net

Как конвертировать значение времени из DateTime в int? Как я понял там нужно сначала в string, а потом в int, но это не работает, ругается компилятор. Пытался сделать это таким кодом

```
string gg = dateTimePicker1.Text.ToString();
int ff = Convert.ToInt32(gg);
Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "/s /t " + ff);
```

Но компилятор ругается на неверные форматы. Я думаю это из за того, что значение времени в DateTime хранится через : (час:минута:секунда).

Щас я пытаюсь сделать 3 string, принимающих значение секунд, минут и часа

```
string second = dateTimePicker1.Value.Second.ToString();
string minutes = dateTimePicker1.Value.Minute.ToString();
string hours = dateTimePicker1.Value.Hour.ToString();
```

Конвертировать потом каждый string в int

```
int min = Convert.ToInt32(minutes) * 60;
int sec = Convert.ToInt32(second);
int how = Convert.ToInt32(hours);
```

Проверять, больше ли how новой переменной nowhow, которая равна DateTime.Now (на этом я сейчас и застрял) и если больше, то новая переменная

```
int sum = min + sec + (how * 3600)
```

И потом

```
Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "/s /t " + sum);
```

Собственно пишу этот вопрос потому что возможно есть способ не мучаться так и по простому перевести, спасибо.

Comment: Если что я хочу есть приложение, которое будет выключать пк по времени, заданном в DateTime. Если нужно, могу отправить интерфейс

Comment: Чему у вас равен `dateTimePicker1.Value`? Это какая то будущая дата или что?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Там я выбираю время, в которое пк выключится. Например через 20 минут, или час https://prnt.sc/iw9k7r

Comment: Кстати, не по теме, просто замечание. Вам не кажется, что лучше в самой программе сделать таймер и после него с небольшой задержкой выключать компьютер? А то представьте, вы задали `shutdown`, приложение упало и не запускается. Через заданное время - компьютер выключился. Подумайте об этом...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала посмотрим в какой нибудь документации, что требуется для значения `\t` у `shutdown`. Немного погуглив узнаем, что это **секунды**.

Хорошо. Теперь несколько сценариев:

1.
У нас есть только некая дата, которая содержит время, которое **должно настать**. Тогда нам из этой даты нужно вычесть `DateTime.Now`.

```
var myTime = new DateTime(2018, 03, 27, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan time = myTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
```

2.
У нас есть дата, которая содержит правильное время, но год и остальные данные в нем "рандомные". Тогда можем создать `TimeSpan` таким образом:

```
var myTime = new DateTime(2018, 03, 27, 0, 0, 0); //DateTime в dateTimePicker1
var newTime = DateTime.Today.Add(new TimeSpan(myTime.Hour, myTime.Minute, myTime.Second)); //Новый 
TimeSpan time = myTime.Subtract(newTime);
```

Можно задаться вопросом, а что делает `Subtract`? В ответ могу сказать, что это некий метод вычитания двух дат. Другими словами `TimeSpan time = myTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);` будет равнозначно `TimeSpan time = myTime - DateTime.Now;`

Хорошо. Зачем нам в итоге нужен `TimeSpan`? Все просто. Теперь мы можем без проблем получить общее число секунд, до указанной даты, `TotalSeconds`. И так, как shutdown скорей всего принимает `int` (а `TotalSeconds` выдаст нам `double`, нужно перевести):

```
int shutdownTime = (int) time.TotalSeconds;
```

Вот собственно и все.